# How to Add textfield in PDF in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

Is it possible to add textfield  and labels and add id's to these fields in PDf file ,  so that we can access these fields later by their corresponding id's ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes like this:

```
 CGContextBeginPage(yourPDFContextRef,nil);

 //Draw view into PDF
 UIView *aPageNote=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 612, 892)]; //provide height and width of pdf page
 aPageNote.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

 //turn PDF upsidedown
 CGAffineTransform aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,892);
 aCgAffTrans = CGAffineTransformScale(aCgAffTrans, 1.0, -1.0);
 CGContextConcatCTM(yourPDFContextRef, aCgAffTrans);

 //add UI Control here to UIVIEW
 UIImageView *aImgViewSign = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            aImgViewSign.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:index];
 [aPageNote addSubview:aImgViewSign];    
 [aPageNote.layer renderInContext:yourPDFContextRef];
 [aPageNote release]; 
 CGContextEndPage (yourPDFContextRef);
```